# JS: how to execute a function after a button is pressed n times?

Tags: javascript, function, button, execution

Suppose i have to make a login system in which it will login only after a button is pressed n times, In Javascript, I don't think this would be easy as there is no commonly used method for it.
Can anyone provide a clue?

```js
var ctr = 0;
function cnt() {
ctr++;
if(ctr==5) {
alert("did it");
}
}
```

```html
<button onClick="cnt()">click me</button>
```

Comment: What have you tried ? Can we see ? (just create a variable that count each time you click. Use a condition if the number is reached and execute your action)

Comment: Each time a button is clicked, you increment a counter. When the counter reaches a threshold, you trigger a given behavior.

Comment: store the count in local storage or increment the count, enable login

Comment: Can we have some context in form of code?

Comment: @AhmedBajra yeah, see now

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this https://jsfiddle.net/opcbnswe/2/

```
$('#btn').on("click", function() {
    $.data(this, "counter", ($.data(this, "counter") || 0) + 1);
    if ($.data(this, "counter") === 5) {
        alert("5 times");
    }
});
```